# Finding the bound state energies in the MIT bag model numerically for a general bag shape

Tags: computational-physics, dirac-equation

The MIT Bag Model is a simple model used to describe the properties of bound quarks in Hadrons, without considering the strong interaction between the quarks with the following boundary condition

$$(1+i(\hat{n}.{\gamma}))\psi \bigg|_{Boundary}=0$$

that sits in the free dirac equation:

$$(i\hbar \gamma ^{\mu }\partial _{\mu }-mc)\psi (x)=0 $$

The problem that I'm starting with is confinement in a sphere, so we have spherical symmetry and we can basically turn this into an ODE for the radial part. Assuming that the solution is in the form of

$$\Psi^k_{j,j_3} = \begin{pmatrix}g_\kappa(r)y_{j l_A}^{j_3}  \\
if_\kappa(r)y_{j l_B}^{j_3}
\end{pmatrix}$$

we get the following system of ODEs:

$$\frac{df_{\kappa}(r)}{dr}+\frac{1-\kappa}{r}f_{\kappa}(r)=(m-E)g_{\kappa}(r)$$
$$\frac{dg_{\kappa}(r)}{dr}+\frac{1+\kappa}{r}g_{\kappa}(r)=(m+E)f_{\kappa}(r)$$

and the MIT boundary conditon translates to:

$$ (f + g) |_R = 0 $$

The problem we have here is that $E$ is also unknown and needs to be determined. It is possible to analytically solve this set of equations with answers in the form of spherical Bessel functions. And we can do this by assuming $\Psi(r \rightarrow 0)$ is finite.

Assuming all of this we can find the bound state energy levels. Now we wanted to do this numerically, and to do so, we used `solve_bvp` and to numerically find the energy levels, we minimized the following expression:

$$ \int (f^2 + g^2) dr$$
doing this, we got the energy levels exactly as in the analytical solution, accurate to 10 decimal places.  A more detailed explanation of our work is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b1IAOAMLRZqvbY2V7dNtNe55LUOmPGx0/view?usp=sharing). But the problem we have here, is the fact that the Neumann solutions basically diverges at $r=o$ and does this in a way that this optimization removes the answers that include the Neumann functions. But generally and specially going into a more general problem that does not have this sort of symmetry, I do not know what to replace this optimization with so that it removes all of the inconvenient answers (the ones that diverge but still may be normalizable). This becomes obvious when we try to optimize $\Psi^2$ (which itself is $ \int (f^2 + g^2) r^2 dr$ ) and find that it produces different answers. So, in a general case I don't know what to do.

*TLDR, how to effectively find the bound state energies in the MIT bag model numerically for a general bag shape?*

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I suspect that you will have to start by finding the eigenvalues of the laplacian with Neumann and Dirichlet BC's for a generally shaped region.  Do you have good numerical procedures for this?

Comment: I can't seem to understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate more? @mikestone

Comment: You are trying to solve an extremely difficult problem.  Do you have the numerical tools to solve a much simpler,  but still very hard,  one in the same general area? If you do, they can probably be adapted to help.